# SASS calculate HSL Difference between 2 colours

Tags: css, sass

I'm using SASS for some styling. I have a base colour, and I want all other colours to change relative to the base colour. I have set the colours up how I want them but the colours are hard coded and not calculated from the base colour.

Is there a tool that quickly generates SASS colour functions for the difference between two colours? There is this tool: http://sassme.arc90.com/ - but it only allows me to generate the output colour with sliders, instead of setting output colour myself and it generate the function.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check out the following resource:

## [Building Color Palettes with SASS](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-sass-build-color-palettes/)

Basically, here's the meat of it:

```
@function color-diff($a, $b) {
  $sat: saturation($a) - saturation($b);
  $lig: lightness($a) - lightness($b);
  $fn-sat: if($sat > 0, 'desaturate', 'saturate');
  $fn-lig: if($lig > 0, 'darken', 'lighten');
 
  @return (
    adjust-hue: -(hue($a) - hue($b)),
    #{$fn-sat}: abs($sat),
    #{$fn-lig}: abs($lig)
  );
}
```

You want to do this with a function in SASS (or a parameterized mixin in LESS), and you can see the structure of one above.

Hope this helps.